# how to match one latitude and longitude in between two points(source and destination)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm working on the carpool/rideshare app. I have driver source and destination, I need to find out the user location between driver source and destination.I'm using Node Js.

For E.g: Let say, Driver source is Noida sec 37 and destination is Noida sector 62. and user source is Logix city center and the destination is Noida 63.

Comment: You want to calculate distance between two locations?

Comment: Try using google waypoint apis for this.

Comment: Ravi Kumar - No

Answer (score 0):

From geometry standpoint, midpoint between two given would be something like:

```
var a = {x: 1, y: 1};
var b = {x: 5, y: 5};
const midPoint = (a, b) => {
    let mid = {};
    mid.x = (b.x + a.x)/2;
    mid.y = (b.y + a.y)/2;
    return mid;
};
console.log(midPoint(a, b));

{x: 3, y: 3}
```

Or, am I missing something?